# Show $ \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i(0)x_i^{j} = 0 $ Lagrange-interpolation-coefficients.

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

Consider the Lagrange-interpolation-coefficients $\lambda_i$ ( $0 \leq i \leq n$) with  nodes $x_0, x_1,..., x_n$.

Show: $$ \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i(x) = 1 $$ and

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i(0)x_i^{j} = 0 $$ for $j = 1,2,...,n$.

Remark: $\lambda_i(x)$ =$\prod_{j=0;i\neq j }^n \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}.$

*My work* :

So first claim was no big deal. Define $f(x) :=   \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i(x) $. 
Then $f(x)$ has at most degree $n$, because the $\lambda_i$ has degree $n$. It holds: $f(x_i) = 1 $for $i=0,...,n$. Consider : $g(x) = f(x)-1$.
Then $g(x)$ has at most degree $n$ and $g(x_i) = 0$ for $i=0,...,n$.  So $g(x)$ has $n+1$ roots. but $g(x)$ has at most degree $n$. We get that $g(x) = 0 $, which means $ \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i(x) = 1 $.

For the second claim we could consider the left side of the equation as interpolation-polynomial, that is evaluated at the point $0$. But this only an idea. Here I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique polynomial of degree $\leq n$ interpolates $(x_0,x_0^j),...,(x_n,x_n^j)$ is $f(x)=x^j$. Now consider Lagrange interpolation and put  $x=0$.

Comment: So my attempt is ( correct me, if there is a mistake) : When we interpolate the function $f(x)=x^j$ the interpolation polynomial (in the Lagrange form) is $P(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n f(x_k) \lambda_k(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x_{k}^j \lambda_k(x)$  . For any $x_1,..., x_n$, the data are perfectly interpolated by polynomial $P(x) = f (x) = x^j$. Since the interpolation polynomial is unique, we have $x^j = P(x) $. Then we put $x=0$. I'm sorry this is the first time I see interpolation. So I'm an amateur.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.